# What is my machine's IP address on an ad-hoc network (computer-to-computer)

Tags: macos, networking, localhost

**Ideal Scenario:**

I'm off the grid. I have my laptop and phone. I want to view a website hosted on my laptop from my phone. I create a network using my macbook using the "Create Network..." option. I connect to that network using my phone. I navigate to the local site from my phone using my macbook's IP address.

**Issue:**

I can't figure out the IP address of my machine on this computer-to-computer network. Using ifconfig doesn't really give me any good information. Maybe I don't understand how this type of network is structured. I imagined that my macbook would function as a router, providing a DHCP function and that all machines on the network would be assigned a 192.168.. IP address.

Anyone know how this actually works? Any alternative suggestions for hosting test sites completely off the grid? I'll be testing mobile website prototypes in places where wifi or internet access may be unavailable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ad-hoc networks without central DHCP server, devices will [auto-assign themselves addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) in the `169.254.x.x` range. This will take a minute or so since the devices are looking for a DHCP response first and will also do some self-discovery regarding their self-assigned address.

You will find the self-assigned address in the Network settings on both devices, or `ifconfig` should also do it.

The alternative would be for you to manually assign an address for each device in its settings.

Comment: This worked. I wasn't waiting long enough for the self assigned IP's. I had found the 169.254.x.x IP for my mac, but I don't think I was patient enough with the phone. The phone reported not being connected to the web. After waiting a while (~30-60s) the phone started working and receiving from the site on my mac. Thanks!